# How to use a mod-like operation on a random string of text, in either PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem whereby I'd like to order a set of items randomly, but consistently.

E.g. given the set: `Apples Bananas Grapes Limes Pineapples`

I might want `Limes Pineapples Apples Grapes Bananas`
or `Grapes Bananas Pineapples Apples Limes`

I don't care what the order is, so long as it's not anything obvious like alphabetical/length etc.  I'd rather not have to STORE the order, and I want it to be repeatable, so I'm after a simple algorithm.

For example, if these were numbers rather than strings, say `10000 12345 12444 17654 199999` I might mod 173 (or whatever) them, and sort by that, to give:

`17654 199999 12345 10000 12444`

How can I do something similar with utf8 strings?  It'd be good to have a solution that worked for arbitrary length, but in my situation they can range from 2 characters to 63 characters.

I could loop through the string and sum all of the characters unicode codes, but I feel there's probably a much more cunning/simple way.  Ideally something I can put in a relatively concise manner in a MySQL query.

Thank you!

Comment: Hash the strings and order by that.

Comment: Of course @Barmar, I knew it was blindlingly obvious and my brain was failing me - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate a hash of the strings and order by that:

```
SELECT string
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY MD5(string);
```